# How to properly test redirect and what happens after in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, phpunit

I have simple route redirect to lang like this:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && in_array(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2), config('blog.locales'))) {
        $locate = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    } else {
        $locale = config('app.fallback_locale');
    }

    return redirect()->to($locale);
});
```

The problem occurs when I want to test it via PHPUnit like this:

```
public function testRedirectToLang()
{
    $response = $this->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(302);
    $response->assertRedirect('/en');
}

public function testBlogPostsFetch()
{
    $posts = Models\Blog\Posts\Post::factory(10)->hasTranslations()->create();

    $response = $this->followingRedirects()->get('/');

    $response->assertStatus(200);
    
    $response->assertSee('<article class="post-short flex flex-wrap">', FALSE);
}
```

If I run both tests the second one fails:

[image: Run 2 tests]
[image: Error for second test]

If I run only second test it passes:

[image: Run 1 test]

So basically something happens after first test which produces 404 for second test.

In general route works live fine for a few years. Just now decided to write tests...

Added print of routes in to the tests and it seems to be empty after first test...

[image: route list]